# Still confusion about Context

Tags: android, android-context

I am new to android...

Maximum time I have to faced the `context` class which sometimes make me confused.
In Some place it use `context`,
somewhere it is called by  `getApplicationContext()`, `getContext()`, `getBaseContext()`.

I tried to make me understand about it from this site,
http://www.developer.android.com/, but it was difficult to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Android, a Context is used for many operations but mostly to load and access resources. This is why all the widgets receive a Context parameter in their constructor. In a regular Android application, you usually have two kinds of Context, Activity and Application. It's usually the first one that the developer passes to classes and methods that need a Context:

You can get the context by invoking getApplicationContext(), getContext(), getBaseContext() or this (when in the activity class).

Typical uses of context:

1. **Creating New objects: Creating new views, adapters, listeners:**

   TextView tv = new TextView(getContext());
   ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), ...);
2. **Accessing Standard Common Resources: Services like
   LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE, SharedPreferences:**

   context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)
   getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(*name*, *mode*);
3. **Accessing Components Implicitly: Regarding content providers,
   broadcasts, intent**

   getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, ...);

you have to be careful when using context because maintaning it can cause to memory leaks

In summary, to avoid context-related memory leaks, remember the following:

1. *Do not keep long-lived references to a context-activity (a reference
   to an activity should have the same life cycle as the activity
   itself)*
2. *Try using the context-application instead of a context-activity*
3. *Avoid non-static inner classes in an activity if you don't control
   their life cycle, use a static inner class and make a weak reference
   to the activity inside. The solution to this issue is to use a
   static inner class with a WeakReference to the outer class, as done
   in ViewRoot and its W inner class for instance*
4. *A garbage collector is not an insurance against memory leaks*